# Evans PDE derivation of solution for Poisson's equation - integration by parts

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

In Evans' PDE text, when proving the solution to Poisson's equation, when he integrates by parts he takes the inward pointing normal, whereas in the integration by parts formula in the appendix, it uses the outward pointing normal.

This is probably a very elementary question but what is going on here?

The fact that it is the inward pointing normal is important and comes in to play in the next few lines. So I'm hoping to get over this minor obstacle!

Comment: I do not have the book with me, but I believe he was being careful when he take the orientation of the manifold. He was probably working with a manifold with outside pointing inwards with respect to the origin, etc.

Comment: If you believe this could be a typo (it happens) you should check his online typo list. The chance of catching a typo in beginning chapters is quite slim, though.

Comment: Yes, 'outside was pointing inwards with respect to the origin' as it was integrating the complement of a ball centred at the origin. Would this change it? I don't see how...

Comment: Oh wait - yes - once I think about it, you're right. Thank you!!! All makes sense